# Display CSS DIV if something exists after # in the URL?

Tags: javascript, html, css, url, display

Is there a way for CSS to change its properties if there's a value after a "#" in the URL? For example, if I click a link which turns my page from /book.php to /book.php#read, is there a way to make a CSS DIV become visible?

I can probably accomplish this with JavaScript (though it will be a slight pain) but I'm wondering if there's a CSS method which can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think CSS can do this. It's fairly easy with javascript.

Comment: you can get href using window.location.href . it think you cant with css

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript), reading the querystring.. you can do what you want in  ```$(document).ready()``` function.

Comment: Perhaps the target selector can be of help ... https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood the question correctly, it is possible to do this with css only using the `:target` pseudo-class from CSS.

Here is an example of how it works:

```css
:target{
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<a href="#content1">Hide Content 1</a>
<a href="#content2">Hide Content 2</a>

<p id="content1">Content 1</p>
<p id="content2">Content 2</p>
```

you can learn more here:

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp)

[developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:target)